# How could visible light be in pitch-black? Can it be?

Tags: big-bang-theory

How could visible light be in pitch-black? Can it be?

Comment: Read the sentence the correct way around. It's pitch black at visible wavelengths. As opposed to radio wavelengths, where it is not pitch black, but glowing.

Comment: By sky, they mean deep space, not our nice blue atmosphere. Olbers' paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers'_paradox

Comment: It seems you interpret the sentence as "the light is black", but it's just a way of saying "there _is_ no light (at optical wavelengths, but there is at radio wavelengths)".
I don't see why people would downvote your question, though.

Comment: @pela you should make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Black is not a color; it is the absence of light.

I think you interpret the sentence as "the light is black", but it's just a way of saying "there is no light (at optical wavelengths, but there is at radio wavelengths)".

In my opinion this is not a good way of explaining the CMB. The sky is *not* black at any wavelengths, but has a background radiation at all wavelengths. In the optical, this background originates (primarily) from the integrated light from stars; in the microwave it originates (primarily) from the afterglow of Big Bang; in the infrared from dust, etc.

See the figure in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/196373/70207) to a question about the number density of CMB photons, to see how large the background is in various wavelength regions.